# Use namespace within control structure (if-statement)

Tags: php, facebook, if-statement, namespaces, control-structure

This works:

```
require_once( $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/fb/FacebookSession.php' );
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
```

This doesn't:

```
if (1 == 1) {
    require_once( $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/fb/FacebookSession.php' );
    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
}
```

It returns the following error:

> **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in **/fb.php** on line **3**

### How can I use a namespace within a control structure?

Comment: This is because the importing is done at compile time and not runtime.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Aha, I see, thank you. So if I have `require` and `use` in a separate php-file (`<?php require(...); use ...; ?>`) and require that within the if-statement (`if (1 == 1) { require(namespace.php); }`), it will work?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the fully qualified class name:

```
$session = new \Facebook\FacebookSession();
```

Or if you need to dynamically select classes:

```
$class = '\\Twitter\\TwitterSession';

if (1 == 1) {
    require_once( $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/fb/FacebookSession.php' );
    $class = '\\Facebook\\FacebookSession';
}

$session = new $class();
```